# Disable automatic Rosetta translation for `.pkg` applications

Tags: macos, monterey, rosetta-2

When I'm installing Microsoft Office for Mac (universal), the installer hangs at the end. Checking the logs, I see that it's because `oahd` is translating the Intel part. I do not use any plugins, so I do not intend running Microsoft Office in Rosetta. This means that I now have ~5 GB of "trash" on my SSD that I can't even delete (protected by SIP). Is it possible to disable this behavior?

The install logs are uploaded [here](https://github.com/sclsj/log/raw/master/%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85%E5%99%A8%E6%97%A5%E5%BF%977-Feb-2022%20Office.txt) to verify that the whole Office suite is translated, not just Microsoft Teams.

Proof that the main Office apps are universal app:

```
file '/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word'
/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
- Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64]
/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

Comment: I've installed MS Office 2021 on an M1 without any such hangs. MS Teams is the only Intel-only app in the Office suite. Are you sure that the Trash is protected by SIP, and not just 'in use'? (Have you tried deleting it after a restart?) The problem is fixing the hang and deleting the trash, not disabling rosetta.

Comment: @benwiggy I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. When it's hang at the last step, I'm looking at the log (command-L) and a bunch of oahd translation related messages scroll by. Later when I reviewed, it seems like it translated every app, and that's why it took so long (I think around 2-3 minutes).

Comment: @JoyJin Are you sure this is a universal build of the Office apps? What does `file '/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word'` show?

Comment: What makes you think it's the oahd translation. That seems to complete (taking about 30 seconds), and the logs suggest that the installation finishes in reasonable time. Tell us about the files in Trash.

Comment: @benwiggy My bad, I should have quoted the trash. What I mean is that oahd translated these applications that I never intended to run in Rosetta, and stored them in `/var/db/oah`. This path is protected by SIP by default, which means I cannot manage this cache whatsoever.

Comment: @GordonDavisson See my edit.

Comment: @benwiggy I see these kind of messages: `Feb  7 21:07:08 JindeMacBook-Pro installd[1033]: oahd translated /Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word`. I don't know how else can you interpret it other then that oahd is automatically translating MS apps.